# Where can I get ammo for the weapon "Nuke"?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm looking for ammo for the weapon called **Nuke**, which runs on **regular nukes and not mini nukes**.

**Its stats are:**
(damage) 2344
(ammo) Nuke
(fire rate) 0
(range) 203
(accuracy) 74
(weight) 41.2
(value) 800

Comment: I recommend editing the question (from title) in your question text.

Comment: @kalina pls. "Itss stats are"

Comment: leave no evidence

Comment: Im finding no evidence of the existance of a regular nuclear launcher in fallout 4, perhaps you could give more information?

Comment: `(fire rate) 0`?

Comment: You might want to share how you acquired the weapon, as it might shed some light on to the answer. Do you have any mods installed? Is this something you spawned from the console? I don't think it's actually a finished functional usable in-game weapon...

Answer (score 3):

I found the ammo ID: it's 65df3, and the weapon ID is 65df2.

If you open the console command and type "player.additem 00065df3 [amount]", you will have ammo for the nuke weapon.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that the console was used to get the weapon. You should at least mention whether the ammo exists somewhere in the world or not.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the dev area via coc qasmoke, and although I was able to find the weapon "Nuke" there is no ammo in the dev area at all, leading me to believe that it doesn't exist, and simply was never programmed. Even consulting [this spreadsheet of all item IDs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9quAMtGK70aptz0t5teqWHGZJ9T9uvJmzNEBJEB36Q/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true) I was unable to find any ammo (though it did list the weapon itself).